# Parsing shebang with sed failure

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I have a string like `#!/bin/bash --args blah blah` and I want to extract "bash" from it.

```
str="#\!/bin/bash --args blah blah"
echo "$str" | sed -r s/#\!.*?/(.*?)\>/\1/g
```

and it gives me an error "bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('".

I enabled extended regex with `-r`, didn't I? what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

You should quote your sed command:

```
echo "$str" | sed -r "s/#\!.*?/(.*?)\>/\1/g"
```

In bash, parens have a special meaning if they're not inside of a string literal.
In addition, your sed command will throw an error for `sed: -e expression #1, char 18: unknown option to 's'` because you have an unescaped `/` in your pattern.

Comment: Probably true, but now it gives me error "sed: -e expression #1, char 18: unknown option to `s'"

Comment: @MightyPork - Correct.  It's because your search pattern contains an unescaped `/`.  You can either escape it or use an alternate delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your string assignment is wrong and also use a different sed delimiter since the input contain forward slashes.

```
$ str='#!/bin/bash --args blah blah'
$ sed -r 's~#![^ ]*/([^ ]*)\b.*~\1~g' <<< $str
bash
```

Answer (score 0):

Using pure BASH built-ins:

```
str='#!/bin/bash --args blah blah'
[[ "$str" =~ \#\!/[^/]+/([^/ ]+) ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
bash
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure POSIX, no bashisms, works for **any** Bourne Shell:

```
$ str='#!/bin/bash --args blah blah'
$ shebang=${str%% *}      # Remove space and all that follows
$ shell=${shebang##*/}    # Remove up to and including /
$ echo $shell
bash
```

Read the section "Parameter Expansion" in your shell manual to find out more about those built-in string processing features. Note that forking an external program like `sed` is **extremely expensive** in terms of CPU cycles, compared to using shell built-in features.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use PCRE:

```
echo '#!/bin/bash --args blah blah' | grep -Po "(?<=/)[a-z]+(?= )"
```

Here the positive lookbehind `(?<=/)` ensures that `/` precedes the regex and positive lookahead `(?= )` ensures that a space follows the regex. So, only `bash` is selected as output.